# A countable product of many sequentially compact spaces is a sequentially compact space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness

I would like to show that a countable product of sequentially compact spaces is a sequentially compact space.

To show that a product of N sequentially compact spaces is sequentially compact, I think that we can take a sequence $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N)$ in the product of sequentially compact spaces, and say that each sequence $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N$ is in the sequentially compact space $X_i$, so has a convergent subsequence.
Then the global sequence converges to the sequence of  limits of the sequences $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_N$.

I don’t understand why this reasoning would not work in the case of an infinite product space and how to prove, then, the result.

Comment: Diagonalize. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288007/countable-product-of-sequentially-compact-spaces-is-sequentially-compact).

Comment: Thank you but I don’t undestand the answer given  it seems to be more an explanation of the principle of diagonalizing than a proof